# Cannot open activity as Dialog in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I need to start activity as dialog. I found a way to do it by setting dialog theme in manifest. But when I start activity, it is giving me error.

This is how I configure in manifest

```
       <activity android:name=".ReplyActivity"
            android:label="Reply"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
            <action android:name="com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.SettingsActivity"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </activity>
```

This is how I start activity in adapter

```
    private void openReplyActivity(int position)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReplyActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(ReplyActivity.NOTI_ID_FIELD,values.get(position).getId());
        intent.putExtra(ReplyActivity.REPLY_TO_FIELD,values.get(position).getUsername());
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

This is XML layout for dialog activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/reply_tv_to_title"
            android:text="Reply to"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/reply_tv_reply_to"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/reply_tf_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:layout_below="@+id/reply_tf_message"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="Reply"
            android:id="@+id/reply_btn_send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the error I get in Logcat

```
06-15 07:17:08.092 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4b65648)
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion.ReplyActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:310)
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:279)
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:253)
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion.ReplyActivity.onCreate(ReplyActivity.java:25)
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
06-15 07:17:08.096 20542-20542/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I set support library in Gradle like this

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

What is wrong with my code? Why can I not start activity as dialog with code?

Comment: *This is the error I get in Logcat* `...Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity...` ... seems like you have problems with reading

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <activity
        android:name=".YourDialogActivityName"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog"
        >
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Why we have to add android:launchMode="singleInstance" please? It is working even without it. Please may u explain me? Thanks for help.

Comment: Answer with just code are not good answers. Please consider adding appropriate explanation.

Comment: @AbdulFatir bro i also add Link for That https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en